# Attempt to read property post_id on int

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm

I have a small response from db model, and i colud rebase it and response in route, but i see error.

My Controller:

```
class PostController extends Controller {
public function getLastRecord() {
    $lastRec = Post::latest('created_at')->first();

    $res = [];

    $res = collect($lastRec)->map(function($record) {
        return [
            'id' => $record->post_id,
            'rec_name' => $record->post_name,
            'user' => $record->user_id,
        ];
    })->toArray();

    return $res;
}
```

}

I want that response will be array

```
['id': 1, 'rec_name': 'test_name', 'user': 1]
```

instead names from db

```
['post_id': 1, 'post_name': 'test_name', 'user_id': 1]
```

Error:

```
Attempt to read property "post_id" on int
```

Comment: What line of code triggers that error? I don't see anywhere you're trying to access `id`, something like `$variable->id`. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73636444/edit) with more details, including the code that actually generates the error.

Comment: look now, please)

Comment: Ok, but I still don't see `->id` _anywhere_ in your code... What line of code is triggering that error??

Comment: Sorry..error: "Attempt to read property post_id on int".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `collect()` a single Record, then call `->map()` (or other iterative methods), it loops over your Model's columns, not multiple `Post` records. You can solve this by wrapping `$lastRec` in an array, or using `->get()` instead of `->first()`:

```
$lastRec = Post::latest('created_at')->first();

return collect([$lastRec])->map(function($record) {
  return [
    'id' => $record->post_id,
    'rec_name' => $record->post_name,
    'user' => $record->user_id,
  ];
})->toArray();

// OR

$lastRecs = Post::latest('created_at')->get();

return $lastRecs->map(function ($record) {
  return [
    'id' => $record->post_id,
    'rec_name' => $record->post_name,
    'user' => $record->user_id,
  ];
})->toArray();
```

Or, since this is a single record (using `->first()` only ever returns 1 record), you don't need to `collect()` or `map()` at all:

```
$lastRec = Post::latest('created_at')->first();

return [
  'id' => $lastRec->post_id,
  'rec_name' => $lastRec->post_name,
  'user' => $lastRec->user_id
];
```